# AJAX request not working properly in core-scaffold of polymer

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, polymer

This link works on the main page

```
<div class="li">
    <a href="rate.php?p=2">
        cool
    </a>
</div>
```

But when I make it in another file and I tried to import it, the ajax does not work properly and make a redirection.

The main page looks like this:

```
<core-scaffold id="core_scaffold">
    ...
    <stores-page id="stores-page"> 
        Here the imported file using ajax 
    </stores-page>
</core-scaffold>
```

Comment: How are you including the main page when you import it in another file?  If you are using a document.ready function to fire the ajax, it may not be firing when the page is including.  You would have to 'load' the main page to get the function to work.

Comment: @Shaggy 
yes you are right, I am using the document ready. How to load the main page to get the function work ?

Comment: You need to include a bit more code to figure out what you are trying to do.  Include the main page where the link works, the page that you are including the main page in, and the ajax call

Comment: The page included:                                                                            '<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rating.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="stores-page2" noscript> 
 <template> 
<div class="li"><a href="controller/rate.php?p=2">cool</a></div>
 </template>     
</polymer-element>
<stores-page></stores-page>'

Comment: The ajax called :                                                                                                                   '$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".li a").click(function(){
    page=$(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
      url: page,
      cache:false,
      success:function(html){
        affich(html);
      },
      error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus);
      }
    })
    return false;

  })
})
function affich(data){
    $(".li").empty();
    $(".li").append(data);
  }
'

Comment: This is The main page:

Comment: <html>
<head>
<link rel="import" href="education.html">
<script src="components/jquery/dist/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rating.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
<core-scaffold id="core_scaffold">
 <core-header-panel mode="seamed" id="core_header_panel" navigation flex>
        <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar"></core-toolbar>
   </core-header-panel>
    <div class="li"><a href="controller/rate.php?p=2">cool</a></div>

<stores-page2 id="stores-page2"> </stores-page2>
</core-scaffold>
</polymer-element>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I do not put all the code. it's too long

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and post the code. It's not ideal sifting through comments and it doesn't help anyone who looks at this question.